# Maximal acyclic subgraph

Tags: graph-theory

It is well known that the problem of finding a maximal acyclic subgraph of a digraph is NP-complete.

Is this the case also when the digraph is symmetric ,i.e. if $(a,b)$ is a link, then $(b,a)$ is also a link?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Arbitrarily label the vertices $1,\ldots,n$.  Choose all edges $a\to b$ such that $b\gt a$.  This is acyclic and exactly half the directed edges in the graph, which is obviously the best possible.

If the edges are weighted then it is again NP-complete, since the weights of $a\to b$ and $b\to a$ can be chosen with sufficient disparity to mimic the standard digraph case.

Comment: Excellent! What if each link has a weight and I want to find the acyclic subgraph with maximal total weight?